# Ocaml pause Unix select

Tags: ocaml, pause

I want to make a function which can make a pause less then 1 sec.
So I have made this function :

```
let pause(n:float)=
Unix.select [] [] [] n
;;
```

And I use it like this :

```
ignore(pause(0.1));
```

And the top level return me this error :

```
Exception: Unix.Unix_error (Unix.EINTR, "select", "").
```

What should I do ?

P.S. I have also tried with `Thread.delay` but I have same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means a signal was sent to your program during the call to `select`.

Assuming you are using OCaml 4.03 or higher, you can use the `Unix.sleepf` function which does exactly what you expect:

```
# Unix.sleepf;;
- : float -> unit = <fun>
```

On older versions of OCaml, you can use the `setitimer` function, which will require some signal handling:

```
exception Alarm
let () = Sys.set_signal Sys.sigalrm ( Sys.Signal_handle (fun _ -> raise Alarm) )

let pause f =
  let _ = Unix.setitimer Unix.ITIMER_REAL
            { Unix.it_interval = 0.; Unix.it_value = f; } in
  try Unix.sleep (int_of_float (ceil f)) with
  | Alarm -> ()
```

Note that this is not really thread safe and would conflict with other uses of `SIGALRM`. I strongly suggest you switch to the most recent version of OCaml.

Comment: I am currently using Ocaml 4.02.3
How can I upgrade to 4.03 ?

Comment: Depends, on what system are you and how did you install OCaml in the first place?

Comment: I am using xfce4 and I install ocaml with Opam I think

Comment: You must have an old version of opam too :) `opam switch <version>` and you're all set.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm new with this environment.. It return me : "4.03.0" is not a valid compiler...
What should I wrote ?

Comment: No problem, I'm here to help. Try doing `opam update` to have the latest list of packages. Then retry to create the switch. If problems persists, maybe you can open a new question (don't forget to indicate your distribution, opam version and other relevant informations).

Comment: Okey, I have also tried opam update, but I't doesn't help :/
I will open a new question.
Perhaps you have an alternative to Unix.sleepf ?

Comment: There is, I'm testing it right now, updating my answer soon.

Comment: Okey so I have tried the second option but I have syntax errors :/ I just copy your code and call pause(0.1)?

Comment: Sys.set_signal Sys.sigalrm ( Sys.Signal_handle (fun _ -> raise Alarm) )
  ^^^
Error: Syntax error

Comment: @FrinkLéo My bad. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks ! Just a question, sometimes the program stop and return me Exception: Alarm.
What should I do ?

Comment: Are you using threads ? If you're using threads, this breaks this solution. Upgrade OCaml.